# Вывести в div текст в зависимости от числа от 1 до 4

Tags: javascript

Как можно сократить этот код js?

Если переменная равна числу от 1 до 4, то в html коде в `<div>` выводится название цифры:

```
if (a == 1) document.getElementById('texts').innerHTML = 'Один!';
if (a == 2) document.getElementById('texts').innerHTML = 'Два!';
if (a == 3) document.getElementById('texts').innerHTML = 'Три!';
if (a == 4) document.getElementById('texts').innerHTML = 'Четыре!';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделать карту значений:

```js
let numbers = [, 'Один', 'Два', 'Три', 'Четыре'];
let a = 2;
document.getElementById('texts').innerHTML = `${numbers[a]}!`;
```

```html
<div id="texts"></div>
```

Если номера могут быть разные, то сделать не через массив, а через объект ключ-значение и уже оперировать им.

```js
let numbers = {1: 'Один', 555: 'Пятьсот пятьдесят пять', 3: 'Три', 16: 'Шестнадцать'};
let a = 555;
document.getElementById('texts').innerHTML = `${numbers[a]}!`;
```

```html
<div id="texts"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое! Это то, что нужно)